# How to add mouse click to a shortcut?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, 18.04

**The problem**:
All this years I have being using Compiz, and Compiz has the ability to execute commands by making shortcuts combining keyboard and mouse.

For example:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + *Mouse Button1 (LeftClick)* = **screenshot section**

That was very useful for me. But now using Ubuntu 18.04 i can't run Compiz.

Is there a way to add click to Gnome shortcuts?

Comment: I can see this example [here](https://superuser.com/a/1264507/628839) where I add that command that emulates  a mouse click but don't know if this is what you want!

Comment: Hi @GeorgeUdosen, that's not what I want... You are simulating the mouse click by pressing some keyboard shortcut. I want to be able to use the mouse for shortcuts